# FlashSocket.IO, policyfile and Socket.IO Error : Failed to load policy file from xmlsocket://localhost:843

Tags: node.js, policyfiles, flashsocket

Following my code for creating the server and policyfile server:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app),  fspfs = require('policyfile')
  , fs = require('fs'), url = require('url');

  flash = fspfs.createServer();

  flash.listen(10081,app, function(){
        console.log(':3 yay');
    });
app.listen(3000);
```

on Flash I initialize the sockets like,
    socket = new FlashSocket("localhost:3000");
    socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.CONNECT,     onConnect);
    socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.MESSAGE, onMessage);
    socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
    socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);

When I run the application I get teh following error:

Error: Failed to load policy file from xmlsocket://localhost:843

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to localhost:3000 halted - not permitted from http://dev/FlashSockets_Demo-debug/FlashSockets_Demo.swf
Error: Request for resource at xmlsocket://localhost:3000 by requestor from http://dev/FlashSockets_Demo-debug/FlashSockets_Demo.swf is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.
```